# WooCommerce Memberships all content older than 2 years make public

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I am going to be using WooCommerce Memberships to restrict the content of my site to members only, however I would also like to make any posts older than 2 years be accessible to or (member or not).

Out of the box, it doesn't seem that the Memberships extension has this capability, however I'm wondering if this could be done programatically, by adding something to the below conditional to check for the current date/time against the published date/time of the post?

```
if( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $membership_plan ) ) {
   // Display restricted content
} else {
   // Display all content to public
}
```